# what's the analogy for the v-item-list-content and v-item-list-icon in vuetify3

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I've noticed, that after upgrading to vuetify.3-beta0.0.0, some of the components that is being used in my project, got disappeared with an error `Failed to resolve component`, some of them is `v-list-item-content` and `v-list-item-icon`, is there any analogies for them in the vuetify3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are inline alternatives now available, `prepend-icon` and `title` as the replacements:

`<v-list-item prepend-icon="mdi-home-roof" title="Dashboard" />`

---

`list-item-content` not implemented but alternatively there is:

`list-item-title` & `list-item-subtitle`.

---

`v-list-item-icon` currently not implemented.

---

https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/